# How to write junit for this code?

Tags: java, junit

How do I call populateMapWithFormattedDates method in JUnit and how to write JUnit populateMapWithFormattedDates for this method. I dont know how to write JUnit for nested methods so kindly help.

```
protected Map<String, String> populateDispatch(final RequestDispatchData requestDispatchData)
    {
        final Map<String, String> map = getDispatchFieldMapper().populateMapper(requestDispatchData);
        populateMapWithFormattedDates(requestDispatchData, map);
 }


private void populateMapWithFormattedDates(final RequestDispatchData requestDispatchData, final Map<String, String> map)
    {
        String dateFormatted = map.get("ticket_date");
        Date date = null;
        try
        {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse(dateFormatted);
        }
        catch (ParseException parseException)
        {
            customLogger.logMessage(diagnosticMethodSignature, DiagnosticType.EXCEPTION,
                    "Exception in parsing start date of ticket " + parseException);
        }
        map.put("startDateDDMMYY", DateEnum.DDMMYY.getFormattor().format(date));
        map.put("startDateDDMMMYY", DateEnum.DDMMMYY.getFormattor().format(date));
        map.put("startDateDMY", DateEnum.DMY.getFormattor().format(date));
        map.put("startDateYYMMDD", DateEnum.YYMMDD.getFormattor().format(date));
    }
```

Comment: If you know what `private` keyword does, you must know you won't be able to call `populateMapWithFormattedDates` in your test class. You need to write tests for `populateDispatch` which will test all the private methods which it calls.

Comment: The theory I prefer is that unit tests should test the publicly visible behavior of a class, which means you shouldn't need to write unit tests for private methods.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you don't test **private** methods directly.

Instead, you focus on the "public contract" of those methods that get invoked "from the outside". In your case, that would be:

```
Map<String, String> populateDispatch(...
```

Thus you want write tests like:

```
@Test
public void populateDispatchForValidDate() {
  RequestDispatchData request = ...
  Map<String, String> actualOutput = underTest.populateDispatch(request);
  assertThat(actualOutput.size(), is(5));
}
```

The above is just meant as an example. What it does:

- create a "request" object. This could be a mock; or a real object - depends on what exactly your various methods are doing with this object. And how easy it is to create a "real" RequestDispatchData object with "test data"
- it invokes that method under test
- it *asserts* one/several properties of the result coming back

Looking at your production code, that code is doing way too many things within that single method. You might want to read about "clean code" and improve that code. That probably lead to the creation of some helper classes which would be easier to test then.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing such as a nested method in Java. It's a nested function call is what it is. Plus, yea, you cannot call the private functions of a class through its object so testing them individually by calling them is not possible.

You can although have a public or protected function doing the call somewhat like a getter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is some what like,

```
protected Map<String, String> populateDispatch(final RequestDispatchData requestDispatchData)
    {
        final Map<String, String> map = getDispatchFieldMapper().populateMapper(requestDispatchData);
        return populateMapWithFormattedDates(requestDispatchData, map);
 }
```

note that you have missed the return statement, and update the map on certain condition from ,

```
private void populateMapWithFormattedDates(final RequestDispatchData requestDispatchData, final Map<String, String> map)
    {
// Map manipulation here
}
```

So if you have minimum dependency on the **getDispatchFieldMapper().populateMapper()**, then you can directly invoke **populateDispatch()** from your test code, else you may have to find a way to inject a custom implementation of DispatchFieldMapper to prepare the map for testing your target method.

Injection of DispatchFieldMapper can be via overriding the **getDispatchFieldMapper()** or use a **setDispatchFieldMapper()** on your class.

While preparing your custom DispatchFieldMapper, make sure the **populateMapper()** returns a map with all data required for your testing.

Answer (score 0):

> It is not good idea to call non accessible  method while testing directly form the test class.
>   Second thing : Non accessible method is always called form some accessible method or scope otherwise that code is dead code just remove that.

Because method is privet, so if it is in use then it called somewhere from code of current class. in your code it called form `populateDispatch`, so actual way to write test case for `populateMapWithFormattedDates` method is cover all the scenarios for `populateDispatch` method and `populateDispatch` is also used form sub class of the current class call it form there.

But you can call private method in junit like:

```
Deencapsulation.invoke(<object of class in called method is exist>, "populateMapWithFormattedDates", <object of RequestDispatchData class>, <object of Map<String, String> class>);
```

Again it is a way to call private method but you should not use this...

Answer (score 0):

You should decouple the populateMapWithFormattedDates method like this:

```
// I created an utility class but it's a suggestion.
// I'm using an util class because you don't use requestDispatchData for
// anything. But if you do, maybe it's a good idea to implement this code
// on RequestDispatchData class
class DispatchMapUtils {
    // Note that I took of the requestDispatchData
    public static Map<String, String> populateMapWithFormattedDates(final Map<String, String> map) throws ParseException {
         // Your code without try-catch. 
         // Throw the exception to the caller of this method
         // and try-catch there to use the customLogger
    }
}
```

With this code, your test would be something like this:

```
@Test
public void shouldFormatTicketDateInVariousFormat() {
     Map<String, String> map;
     // Instantiate and put some initial datas
     map = new ...
     map.put('ticket_date') = ..
     // Call the method!
     DispatchMapUtils.populateMapWithFormattedDates(map);
     // Do the assertions!
     Assert.assertTrue(map.get("startDateDDMMYY").equals(...));
}

@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenTicketDateIsInvalid() {
    // More testing code
}
```